# How to deal with multi-character commenter when lexing with shlex in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, comments, shlex

I want to parse a string with some inline comment blocks like `/* comments */`, and I want to ignore those comments.

For example,

```
>>> import shlex
>>> string = "foo /bar /* this is a test */"
>>> lex = shlex.shlex(string)
>>> list(lex)
['foo', 'bar', '/', '*', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '*', '/']
```

If I add the commenter `/*`, this is interpreted as two commenters `/` and `*`, and I missed the `/bar`

```
>>> import shlex
>>> string = "foo /bar /* this is a test */"
>>> lex = shlex.shlex(string)
>>> list(lex)
['foo']
```

Ideally, I want the result as

```
['foo', '/bar']
```

p.s., as to the comment by @Chillie why not use regular expression. I go for `shlex` because I I do want to use `shlex` to ignore the whitespace in the subquotes of the string.

For example, the real use case can be like

```
>>> import shlex
>>> string = "foo /bar \"value string\" /* this is a test */"
```

and I want to capture the `value string` in the quotes but not split by the whitespace inside the quotes,

```
>>> ['foo', '/bar', '\"value string\"']
```

I am not a regex expert. To design a good pattern for such a case is a bit difficult for me. If someone can come up with a regex solution, I am also fine with that.

Comment: As you have discovered, `shlex` does not support multi-character comment marks. You can use regular expresisons to remove the comments from the string, if the use-case is as simple as you present it.

Comment: The use-case is actually not so simple as in the example code. For example, I do want to use `shlex` to ignore the whitespace in the subquotes of the string. Regular expression was on the list, but seems a bit complicated to design a good pattern to satisfy all the use-cases. @Chillie

Comment: @Chillie, I edit the question to have a more realistic example.